# Requirejs - Configuring require before loading data-main

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

We're using requirejs for the first time, and I'm having trouble structuring my dependencies.

I've defined my main app.js file as the data-main attribute in my index.html:

```
<script data-main="src/app" src="/js/lib/require/require.js"></script>
```

But, I have a file which defines all my require path/shim configurations, and I want that to run before the app.js file. I need it to run so that I can reference configured paths as dependencies in my app.js.

I don't think the right way is to put my config.js as the data-main.
I tried setting the config.js as a dependency like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var require = {
            baseUrl: "/",
            deps: ["src/config"]
        }
    </script>
    <!-- data-main is the main js file of the app -->
    <script data-main="src/app" src="/js/lib/require/require.js"></script>
```

but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try putting the shim/path config options in the `var require = {}`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I load `config.js` in `app.js` to share configuration for each pages.

For instance:

```js
require(['config'], function(){
  require(['module','another'], function(){
    // run with all modules
  });
});
```

To optimize this project, using `has.js` is better way to reduce HTTP connection. For more detail, see [this sample project](https://github.com/eller86/requirejs-best-practice/tree/master/src/combineWithConfig).

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar in order to get the "chaining" effect. I created an init.js file as my data-main, and inside it I did:
`require(['config'], function (appConfig) {
    require(['app'], function(app){
        require(['appStart']);
    });
});`

**config** - holds the require paths configuration.
**app** - creates my app object and some other initialization functions.
**appStart** - kick starts the app.