# Require.js bug random Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

My application use require.js, I have a random bug (happens 1 time for 50 reload)
Require.js write in the console :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Indeed, require.js try to include jquery from a wrong directory...
I don't know why, most of the time the application works fine...

My config is pretty simple :

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    animate_from_to: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    bootstrap: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    zoom: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    shop_util: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    pricer: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    filter: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    paginator: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
  },
  paths: {
    bootstrap:        'lib/bootstrap',
    jquery:           'lib/jquery-1.9.1',
    zoom:             'lib/jquery.zoom.min',
    animate_from_to:  'lib/jquery.animate_from_to-1.0.min',
    backbone:         'lib/backbone.min',
    underscore:       'lib/underscore.min',
    text:             'lib/require-text',
    shop_util:  'lib/shop_util',
    pricer:           'lib/pricer',
    filter:           'lib/filter',
    paginator:        'lib/paginator',
  }

});
```

Thank you

Comment: What directory is it trying to load?

Comment: It tries to load from the directory of the "require.config" file. /js/jquery.js instead of /js/lib/jquery.1-9-1.js

Comment: Interesting.  Do you experience the same behavior in multiple browsers?

Comment: I don't know, I use Chrome and the bug is so uncommon I can't reproduce it

Comment: require.config is in the file 'main.js' called by script : <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems you have another entry point into your application somewhere other than your data-main script (js/main.js). Even if it's a subsequent script in the same page, you cannot depend on your data-main script being completed before the next script runs, [since it's loaded with async attribute](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/546).

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<!-- foo.js might run before js/main.js !!! -->
<script src="js/foo.js"></script>
```

You can prove this by adding a console.log statement at the end of js/main.js and one in foo.js (or whatever). Normally you will see the one from js/main.js and then foo.js , but in that 1 out of 50 case you'll see them happen in the other order.

There are several strategies to deal with this:

**1 - Do all your app initiation and subsequent require's from your data-main script**

Applies to single-page apps, of course. All in one file:

```
require.config({
  // snip
});
require(['mymodule'], function( mymodule ) {
  // do stuff
});
```

**2 - Use an inline script right after the require.js script tag**

Instead of having the above script inside a separate file referenced by data-main, just have a 2nd script tag right below. This is the first example [listed in the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Applies mostly to single-page-apps

**3 - Load your require config into global variable prior to the require.js script tag**

Second example [listed in the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

```
<script>
    var require = {
        paths: { // define them}
        shim: { // define them }
    };
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Applies mostly to single-page-apps

**4 - Nest your require calls to load the the config first**

This works best for multi-page apps and is the one recommended in [the multi-page shim app example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim)

```
<script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script>
    //Load common code that includes config, then load the app
    //logic for this page. Do the require calls here instead of
    //a separate file so after a build there are only 2 HTTP
    //requests instead of three.
    require(['./js/common'], function (common) {
        //js/common sets the baseUrl to be js/ so
        //can just ask for 'app/main1' here instead
        //of 'js/app/main1'
        require(['app/main1']);
    });
</script>
```

Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184631/requirejs-configuring-require-before-loading-data-main), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637042/requirejs-does-not-run-data-main-script-before-loading-required-modules), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386939/how-to-wait-when-data-main-is-loaded-with-require-js-before-executing-script)

Comment: Completely right ! I chose the 4nd method, the most "require.js compliant" according to me. Thank you !

Comment: Isn't require.js supposed to do this anyway, based on the order of files in the array argument?

Comment: @Yuck No, it's not. That's the Async part of AMD -- you don't know in which order the files will be resolved, only that they resolve before calling your function.

Comment: Thank you! This issue has been bugging me for a long time!