# RequireJS + PhoneGap + Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, cordova, requirejs, jquery-mobile

I'm having problem with RequireJS giving me some 'Uncaught TypeError', all i have is the basic structure and when i test it in ripple i often get this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'local_data_exist' of undefined
```

Which is a function in one of my library.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jqmNavigator' of undefined
```

Or this.

So since the errors are not consistant they give me a hard time to debug. Wonder if anyone has face this before.

```
require.config({
    deps:['main'],
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths:{
        // Pointing to Main possible fix for random undefined
        app: 'main',
        // jQuery
        jquery:'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        // jQuery Plugin for Dfp
        dfp: 'libs/jquery/jquery.dfp.min',
        // jQuery Mobile framework
        jqm:'libs/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min',
        // Backbone.js library
        Backbone:'libs/Backbone/Backbone',
        // Backbone.js Adapter
        localStorage: 'libs/Backbone/backbone.localStorage',
        // RequireJS plugin
        text:'libs/require/text',
        // RequireJS plugin
        domReady:'libs/require/domReady',
        // underscore library
        underscore:'libs/underscore/underscore',
        // jQuery Mobile plugin for Backbone views navigation
        jqmNavigator:'libs/jquery.mobile/jqmNavigator',
        //TouchSwipe
        touchSwipe: 'libs/jquery/jquery.touchSwipe.min',
        //Moment (Date Plugin)
        moment: 'libs/moment/moment',
        // Language plugin
        lang: 'libs/moment/langs.min',
        // Utility Lib
        utils: './utils'
    },
    shim:{
        Backbone:{
            deps:['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports:'Backbone'
        },
        app: {
            deps:['jquery','Backbone','underscore'],
            exports: "App"
        },
        underscore:{
            exports:'_'
        },
        dfp : {
            deps:['jquery']
        },
        jqm:{
            deps:['jquery', 'jqm-config', 'jqmNavigator']
        },
        touchSwipe:{
            deps:['jquery']
        },
        lang:{
            deps:['moment']
        },
        utils:{
            deps:['jquery']
        }
    },
    waitSeconds: 200,
    priority: ['jquery']
});

require(['jquery', 'domReady', 'Backbone', 'jqm-router', 'models/ApiModel', 'jqm', 'underscore', 'jqm-config', 'jqmNavigator'],
    function ($, domReady, Backbone, AppRouter, Api) {
        domReady(function(){
            window.Api = Api;
            $(this).router = new AppRouter();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Post your requirejs config so we can see if this is a shimming issue or something else

Comment: I would check for dependency loops. Include [xrayquire](https://github.com/requirejs/xrayquire) and run `xrayquire.showCycles()`. It's not perfect for figuring out how to resolve the loops, but it'll show you if there are any and where to start looking.

Comment: how is this require.config being called vs. how are your other scripts loaded? Could it be something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026036/require-js-bug-random-failed-to-load-resource)

Comment: This seems more plausible, trying right now. @explunit

Comment: Ok this might solve so of the problem even though im still getting errors when it comes to include one of my plugins. I ran xrayquire give me a 'Mixed case modules may conflict: views/pages/ArticleListView asked for: "utils" and views/pages/ArticleView asked for: "Utils"'