# jquery is not loaded when used with require.js

Tags: requirejs

I am using the following code Html to load the scripts that I need.  I am getting **$ as Undefined**.  It is not able to load the jquery.

How can I get this to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using The Text Plugin With RequireJS</title>
<script  data-main="Scripts/init type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    require(['jquery', 'knockout-2.2.1', 'Template', 'text!Template.htm'], function ($, ko, t, temp) {

        $("body").append(temp);
        //make this new template engine our default engine
        ko.setTemplateEngine(t.myExternalTemplateEngine(t.templates));

        ko.applyBindings(t);

    });
</script>
</head>
```

code in Init.js in a separate file

```
require.config({
baseUrl:'Scripts',
paths: {

    'jquery': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js',
    'knockout-2.2.1': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js',
    'knockout.mapping-latest': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.3.5/knockout.mapping.js',
    'Template': 'Template',
    'text': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-text/2.0.5/text',
    'domready': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady/2.0.1/domReady.js'
   }

});
```

Comment: Did you try to use jQuery instead of $ sign ?

Comment: You might be running into the issue that your init.js is not loaded before your script that uses it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026036/require-js-bug-random-failed-to-load-resource/17044595#17044595). What other errors do you have in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .js from your paths configuration:

```
paths: {
    'jquery': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery'
}
```

More detail in [this example repo](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn)

Comment: good catch -- didn't see that. But regardless, the script loading approach is going to hit some random errors based on timing. See question I linked above.

Comment: Good point, wrapping it in a `require(['init'])` will stop the issue with race conditions.