# When designing a JS library should I make it RequireJS/AMD compatible or not?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

If I'm making a JavaScript library for general use, how should I handle RequireJS support?

As far as I can tell, making your code compliant with RequireJS more or less makes it impossible to use without RequireJS. So why would I do that?

- How do people without Require use this code?
- Is there a way to support both without forking / branching? Should I provide the shim code?
- Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: See [supporting both CommonJS and AMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673346/supporting-both-commonjs-and-amd) and also the source code of many common libraries such as jQuery and Knockout which support both AMD and non-AMD

Comment: UMD looks like it tries to fix every case by adding a lot of complexity. Is there a best practice that is simpler and more flexible?

Answer (score 23):

If you're only dealing with browser (not node.js), it's only a handful of lines to make the library support both AMD and non-AMD.

For example, [here is the file from jQuery that does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports/amd.js), of which all but four are comments:

```
// Execute the factory to produce jQuery
var jQuery = factory( window );

// Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
// files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
// understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
// way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
// derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
// file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
// to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

And a very similar snippet from Knockout can be found [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/amd-pre.js):

```
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
    // [2] AMD anonymous module
    define(['exports'], factory);
}
```

Note that jQuery takes the [named module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) approach while knockout uses an anonymous module. jQuery also leaves `$` and `jQuery` in the global namespace, [even when AMD is detected](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#globalvars), whereas Knockout (and probably many others) do **not** put anything in global namespace when AMD detected. There are pros and cons to each approach, as illustrated by these questions:

- [Correct way to implement jQuery with require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613577/correct-way-to-implement-jquery-with-require-js/15649611)
- [Using ScriptSharp with Knockout.Mapping through RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575048/using-scriptsharp-with-knockout-mapping-through-requirejs)

Comment: Great! So does this approach violate any rules by dirtying the global namespace with it's filthy jQuery variable?

Comment: Note that the location of the amd export functionality has moved to a new file in [src/exports/amd.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports/amd.js)