# How to prevent loading of knockout.js by requirejs?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I'm currently using requirejs for loading majority modules, but i need to load single script knockout.js with old-fashioned manner using:

```
<script src='/path/to/knockout.js' ></script>
```

I have a trouble with it, when page is rendered i see this markup:

```
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="knockout.min.js"></script>
```

But i don't want to load knockout using require.js.

**How to disable loading using require.js for specified script?**

---

***I FOUND A SOLUTION:***

After digging up a sources of `knockout`, i found interesting pice of code, which determine existance of `require.js` and automatically registers module in `require`, Here is a guilty chunk of code:

```
    // Support three module loading scenarios
if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object') {
    // [1] CommonJS/Node.js
    var target = module['exports'] || exports; // module.exports is for Node.js
    factory(target);
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
    // [2] AMD anonymous module
    define(['exports'], factory);
} else {
    // [3] No module loader (plain <script> tag) - put directly in global namespace
    factory(window['ko'] = {});
}
```

You can change as you want (for example you can replace `function` with something else) to achieve executing last `else` branch of code, and as result ko will be registered in global window space.

Comment: Include require.js after you include knockoutjs ?

Comment: I cannot to do that, i'm developing addon to external web application which not allow to change his code. My js scripts declarations followed by scripts declaration of system which i extend. I cannot change that order. Is exists another solution?

Comment: tell us more about how the scripts that actually use knockout are loaded. If your goal is to be sure that the `ko` object is in the global namespace, there are ways to do that within requirejs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575048/using-scriptsharp-with-knockout-mapping-through-requirejs/17582058#17582058

Comment: regarding your "I found a solution" edit: now you have to manually merge your customizations to knockout as they come out with new versions. See the link I posted in the comment above for a better way to to tackle the global namespace issue.